# StretchBlt Only Works When I'm in Aero Mode

Tags: c++

I'm trying to code a joke program(tunnel effect like in MEMZ trojan...).
I'm using StretchBlt but it works only when my pc in Aero mode. What can i do for it to work in any theme ?

My Code;

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <process.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    keybd_event(VK_MENU,0,0,0);
    keybd_event(VK_TAB,0,0,0);
    Sleep(400);
    keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_TAB, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    Sleep(1000);
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(),SW_HIDE);
    RECT masadik;
    HWND masa = GetDesktopWindow();
    GetWindowRect(masa,&masadik);
    int x,y;
    x = masadik.right;
    y = masadik.bottom;
    HDC ali = GetDC(masa);
    int sleeptime = 2100;
    while (0==0){

    StretchBlt(ali,50,50,x - 100,y - 100,ali,0,0,x,y, SRCCOPY);
    Sleep(sleeptime);
    if (sleeptime <= 0){
        sleeptime = 2100;
    }
    else
    {
        sleeptime = sleeptime - 100;
    }
}
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Overlapping calls to StretchBlt are undefined.

Comment: umm, what can i do for that problem? can you help me